# SQL Server backup file growing excessively

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-backups, transaction-log

I am a software developer with not much expertise on SQL Server other than the basics.

On a daily basis, using the SQL Server Agent I back up the databases using the following command for each of the databases:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DatabaseName] 
TO DISK = N'D:\SQLBackups\DatabaseName.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, 
     NAME = N'DatabaseName-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, 
     NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
```

After running this command for several days, the size of the `.bak` file has reached 65 GB and growing.

The database files on the DATA directory are 0.92 GB for the `.mdf` and 1.2 GB for the `.ldf` one. And the database is set to full recovery mode.

Database engine is SQL Server 2008 R2 (version 10.50.2500.0)

If I create a full back using the SQL Server Management Studio interface, it occupies 0.93 GB.

Could somebody please explain how it is possible to reach such a big `.bak` file (65 GB) compared to manually creating a single full back up file?

Comment: It is appending the backups right? So are you asking why even though it is appending does the file grow so large so fast? How many days does it take to get to 65GB

Comment: It took around 5 months to get to 65GB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `NOINIT` option keeps **appending** data to the single `.bak` file. Use this statement to **replace** the existing `.bak` file:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DatabaseName] 
TO DISK = N'D:\SQLBackups\DatabaseName.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, 
     NAME = N'DatabaseName-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, 
     NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
```

All the details can be found in the [official MSDN SQL Server Books Online documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) for the `BACKUP DATABASE` command....